# How to set nth value from an array as default value of $zip, if nth element of zipping array is empty in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

After going through some aggregation pipeline stages, My MongoDB document has the following format(Sample):

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "_id": "group1",
      "start": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
      ],
      "end": [
        "l",
        "m",
        "n",
        "o"
      ],
      "mid": [
        "a1",
        "a2",
        "a3",
        "a4"
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "group2",
      "start": [
        "p",
        "q",
        "r",
        "s"
      ],
      "end": [
        "h",
        "i",
        "j"
      ],
      "mid": [
        "b1",
        "b2",
        "b3"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to transform my data into the following format:

```
{
  "new_data": [
    {
      "_id": "group1",
      "val": [
        {
          "start": "a",
          "end": "l"
        },
        {
          "start": "b",
          "end": "m"
        },
        {
          "start": "c",
          "end": "n"
        },
        {
          "start": "a4",
          "end": "o"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": "group2",
      "val": [
        {
          "start": "p",
          "end": "h"
        },
        {
          "start": "q",
          "end": "i"
        },
        {
          "start": "r",
          "end": "j"
        },
        {
          "start": "s",
          "end": "default value"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Question:
How to handle exceptional cases?

While transposing `start` and `end` arrays,

1. If nth value of `start` is NULL, take nth value from `mid` array as `start` value
2. If nth value of `end` is NULL, use some "default value" as `end` value(This part has solution)

> length of `mid` = length of `end`

Here is What I tried:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
..... some pipeline stages
},
        {
          $unwind:
            {path:"$data"}
        },
        {
          "$project": {
            "data.mid":1,
            "data._id":1,
            "val": {
              "$map": {
                "input": {
                  "$objectToArray": {
                    "$arrayToObject": {
                      "$zip": {
                        "inputs": [
                          "$data.start","$data.end"],
                        useLongestLength: true,
                        defaults: [ *I don't know what to write here*, "default value"] // Need help
                      }
                    }
                  }
                },
                "as": "el",
                "in": {
                  "start": "$$el.k",
                  "end": "$$el.v"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        { "$group": {
          "_id": "$data._id",
          "new_data": {
            "$push": { "transformed_data":"$val" }
          }
        }}
        
        ]).pretty()
```

How to achieve this use case?

Comment: I think `$zip` only allow a single default value, so which value are you going to use from `mid` if the length difference is more than one, for example `start: ["a"], end: ["x", "y", "z"], mid: ["j", "k", "l"]`. or if the length of `mid` is shorter than `end` like `mid: ["j"]` or `mid: ["j", "k"]`

Comment: if  ```start: ["a"]```, ```end: ["x", "y", "z"]```, ```mid: ["j", "k", "l"]```: then ```val:[{
"start": "a","end": "x" },{"start": "k","end": "y" },{"start": "l","end": "z" }]``` And in my case length of ```mid```= length of ```end```. Is this use case achievable using mongoDB pipeline?

Comment: In the last stage of your aggregation, you group by `$data._id`, which I think would output 2 documents with `"group1"` and `"group2"` as `_id`, but you want as the output only one document with an array `newData`. So what do you actually want to use to group at the last stage?

Comment: Actually both are fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible using `$zip`, because `$zip` will replace the missing value with a constant value.

Instead we can iterate over a range with the length of the larger array. It's similar to the approach suggested by [@abid ali](https://stackoverflow.com/u/13513066) in the the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62788021). But using aggregation.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      doc_id: "$_id",
      _id: "$data._id",
      val: {
        $map: {
// constructing a range of the larger array of data.start and data.end, we will get [0, 1, ..., n-1] where n is the size of the larger array
          input: { $range: [0, { $max: [{ $size: "$data.start" }, { $size: "$data.end" }] }] },
          in: {
            start: { // if data.start[i] is null, take data.mid[i] where is the index we are iterating, represented by "$$this"
              $ifNull: [
                {
                  $arrayElemAt: ["$data.start", "$$this"]
                },
                {
                  $arrayElemAt: ["$data.mid", "$$this"]
                }
              ]
            },
            end: { // if data.end[i] is null take a defaultt value
              $ifNull: [
                {
                  $arrayElemAt: ["$data.end", "$$this"]
                },
                "default_value"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // this stage onward is for reshaping the data to the expected output
    $group: {
      _id: "$doc_id",
      new_data: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { "new_data.doc_id": false }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GoMGjqvcZ4U)

Answer (score 1):

This can be answered in simple way

```
if(start.length>=n){
  if(mid.length<n){ 
 const value = mid[n];//giving nth value from mid array
  }
}
else{
const value = start[n];
}


if(end.length>=n){
const value = start[0];//default value
}
else{
const value = end[n];
}
```